# Inserting rows with data upon finding certain value in Column B

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My question is somehow complicated . I will try to simplify it as much as possible.
I have added a link to the sheet for simplicity.
[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z5IrQAiEIABkbRRxCB0YHFpvJRQJ6dzz4jKHbJqxKVg/edit#gid=1567447113)

I have a large table of about 10,000 rows. I want to insert 9 rows after each row containing the word " Test 22" in column B. This is the first stage. The most important part ( stage II) that I want to fill data in these 9 rows as following :

1. Column A (Product Name) cells will contain the same product name as the first cell adjacent to the cell of value "Test 22"
2. Column E ( Empty Column 2) cells which are 9 cells will contain these values (Result 1, Result 2 , Result 3, Result 4 , Result 5 , Result 6 , Average, Max, Min). And of course , this process will be repeated through the whole table upon finding the word " Test 22" in column B.

I have managed successfully to perform stage I which is inserting 9 blank rows after each row containing the word " Test 22" in column B, but I couldn't perform stage II. I don't know if this function could be done in 1 step or 2 steps.
Your help will be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: By sharing spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). Instead, use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/). You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells.

Comment: Hi, dear Yuri , I didn't run I am here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var new_data = [];

  for (var row in data) {
    new_data.push(data[row]);
    if (data[row][1] == 'Test 22') {
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Result 1']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Result 2']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Result 3']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Result 4']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Result 5']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Result 6']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Average']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Max']);
      new_data.push([data[row][0],'','','','Min']);
    }
  }

  sheet.getRange(1,1,new_data.length,new_data[0].length,).setValues(new_data);
}
```

or, about the same algo with less verbose notation:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var new_data = [];
  var col_e = ['Result 1','Result 2','Result 3','Result 4',
    'Result 5','Result 6','Average','Max','Min'];

  for (let row of data) {
    new_data.push(row);
    if (row[1] == 'Test 22') {
      col_e.forEach(e => new_data.push([row[0],'','','',e]));
    }
  }

 sheet.getRange(1,1,new_data.length,new_data[0].length,).setValues(new_data);
}
```

**Update**

The function to format the column F:

```
function format_column_F() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var column = sheet.getRange('E:E').getValues().flat();
  var formats = new Array(9).fill(['0.00 %']);
  var row = 0;

  while (row++ < column.length) {
    if (column[row] == 'Result 1') {

      let range = `F${row+1}:F${row+6}`;
      let formulas = [[`=AVERAGE(${range})`],[`=MAX(${range})`],[`=MIN(${range})`]];

      sheet.getRange(`F${row+7}:F${row+9}`).setFormulas(formulas);
      sheet.getRange(`F${row+1}:F${row+9}`).setNumberFormats(formats);

      row += 9;
    }
  }
}
```

**Refs:**

- [Date and number formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats)
- [Range.setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)
- [Array.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)
- [Template literals `${}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Dear Yuri, I want to thank you so much for your quick and so professional solutions . Both are perfect for me and helped me a lot. Thanks again. I couldn't vote up for your answer as still I don't have the right to vote. But I am sure that I will need your support a lot in the coming days.

Comment: Hello Yuri, It's me again. I will query data from the table that we have just modified to another sheet in the same spreadsheet. I want to format the column adjacent to column e ['Result 1','Result 2','Result 3','Result 4',  'Result 5','Result 6','Average','Max','Min'];

Comment: Hello Yuri, It's me again. I will query data from the table that we have just modified to another sheet in the same spreadsheet. I want to format the cells in the column adjacent to column e ['Result 1','Result 2','Result 3','Result 4',  'Result 5','Result 6','Average','Max','Min']; as follows :  " The first 6 cells adjacent to Result 1 till Result 6 will be in percentage format ( 0.00%). The cell adjacent to the "Average " cell will calculate the average of the 6 results and be also formatted in 0.00 %. The cells adjacent to " Min" and " Max" cells will contain the min& max of the 6 results.

Comment: I've added the additional function to format column F.

Comment: Dear Yuri, Thanks a lot for your quick solution and for sharing the references to increase my knowledge. You are really helpful. I will try the code and feedback you soon

Comment: Dear Yuri, Can you help me with my new question. This is the link : "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73756000/uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-cant-use-import-outside-modu". I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @kerosh I'll see if I can help. But at first glance the problem looks outside my area of expertise.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Yuri. If you need more details about the code , I can send you.